# How can I get to the classificating forms of a finite abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, abelian-groups

I worked through module theory over principal ideal domains, and in the end there are some applications. The example concerning me is the classification of finite abeliean groups.

There are two ways either:

(1) $\,G\cong Z^n\oplus Z/d_1Z\oplus Z/d_2Z\oplus ... \oplus Z/d_rZ\,\,$ with $d_1 |d_2|...|d_r$

(2) $\,G\cong Z^n\oplus Z/p_1^{n_1}Z\oplus ...\oplus Z/p_k^{n_k}Z$ with $p_i$ primes

I agree from the proofs and theorems, that both classifications are valid and unique, but when I try to think about some examples and their forms (1) and (2) im still not sure how to make it properly.

---

First look at: $Z/24Z$ I know from my Algebra courses that $Z/mnZ \cong Z/mZ \oplus Z/nZ$ if $\gcd(m,n)=1$   $(*)$

So I am sure $Z/24Z \cong Z/8Z \oplus Z/3Z$ this looks like form $(2)$. How can I be sure I am already done in regards to form (2), why does $Z/8Z$ not split? Or does it?

And how do I get the (1) form of $Z/24Z$?

---

Second example: $Z/24Z\oplus Z/240Z\cong (Z/8Z \oplus Z/3Z)\oplus(Z/16Z \oplus Z/3Z\oplus Z/5Z)$

the first "split" is again simply by my use of $(*)$. How do I proceed to reach form (2)? And how would I get to form (1)?

Would be great if someone might help me :)

Comment: $(Z/8Z \oplus Z/3Z)\oplus(Z/16Z \oplus Z/3Z\oplus Z/5Z)$ is already in form (2).  All of those numbers are powers of primes.

Comment: Also, both your examples are already in form (1) in their original forms, before you split them up!

Comment: ahh I see, ok I think both example dont fix my question entirely. Lets now look at $Z/2Z \oplus Z/16Z \oplus Z/34Z$ how could I find the form (1) of this group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles over a similar problem:

In order to reach form

(2):

Splitt the Qoutients by the rule $Z/mnZ\cong Z/mZ \oplus Z/nZ$ if $\gcd(m,n)=1$

as often as possible and you are done.

In order to reach form

(1):

Write down the principle ideals generators in a diagonal matrix and
bring the matrix in

**Smith Normalform**

The numbers on the diagonal are the generators of your Quotients generatos.

For example is the (1) form of $Z/2Z \oplus Z/16Z \oplus Z/34Z \cong Z/2Z \oplus Z/2Z \oplus Z/272Z$